# PCB problem - INA321 vias are too big

Tags: current, sensor

I am making a PCB using ULTIBOARD from NI.

The problem is that I use a part called INA321 and for some reason I get the error that my vias are too close to each other when I place vias in the pads for the INA321.

I tried making the vias smaller, but I still get the error.

Is it a bug in the ULTIBOARD program?

[image]

[image]

I tried to check the options of the PCB printing factory  and fount this:

[image]

However, when I changed the via hole size to 0.2mm and via diamter to 0.45 mm I get still this error:

[image]

The only other option I have left is to ignore thrse errors.

Comment: Why do you want/need via in pad?  you have a lot of room around this part to fan out. Via in Pad is expensive and not all fav houses can do it

Answer (score 3):

This is probably not a bug.

Any good PCB design program has what is called a "design rules checker."

These are intended to help you build boards that can be manufactured.

Without such rules, you could design a board that looks good but is beyond the capabilities of the PCB fabricator to actually build.

The design rules checker will have a set of standard rules that it applies until you tell it otherwise.

In your case, it is telling you that you have your vias too close together.  It takes a bit of space around a via for one to be made.  How much space depends on how your PCB fabricator does it.

The rule is probably very conservative (better safe than sorry.)

You have two choices:

1. Check with your PCB fabricator, and see how close they will allow vias (of the size you are using) can be placed, and change the design rules in your program (or just for that project.)
2. Move your vias and "make the rules checker happy."

If you choose the first option and then later change fabricators, you might have to redo the layout because the new fabricator can't space vias as closely as the previous fabricator.

If you leave the design rules as they are, you'll probably be able to take it to **any** fabricator and have it produced with no problems.

Following the default rules means leaving more space, so your board might have to be a bit bigger or you'll have to pack other things tighter.

In either case, leave the design rules check **on.**

It is trying to help you.  Let it help.  Adjust its rules if you need to, but leave it on and pay attention to what it is telling you.

---

For your current problem, you could move the vias out of the pads and spread them apart a little bit.

---

The problem is **not*" how big the vias are, it is how **close to one another they are.** That is measured from the **center** of the vias, not the outer edge.

You have to move them apart.  Making them smaller does **not** change how far apart the centers are.

---

Had a closer look at your pictures.  It is complaing about a **lot** more stuff.

Change your minimum distance between traces to 5mil.  The same for the distance for vias to traces.

5 mil is what your manufacturer recommends as the minimum distance between all features.

Set your design rules to 5 mil.  Then **fix** any violations it shows.

If you don't fix them, your manufacturer will either refuse to make the board or deliver a piece of crap.

Answer (score 2):

You have your vias placed inside of your IC pads.  This will make it difficult to solder by hand, and impossible to reflow.

In general, you run a small trace from the pad to a via, observing clearance rules as you do so.  On a tight board, this can be quite a puzzle.

Here's a shot from a board that I did a few years back showing what you need to do (note that this was from a few years ago, with a manufacturer that demanded rather large features compared to the IC pin pitch).

[image]

Comment: Ok thank your for your help !.